# Sort by key of dictionary inside a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

How to sort the following dictionary by the value of "remaining_pcs" or "discount_ratio"?

```
promotion_items = {
    'one': {'remaining_pcs': 100, 'discount_ratio': 10},
    'two': {'remaining_pcs': 200, 'discount_ratio': 20},
}
```

**EDIT**

What I mean is getting a sorted list of above dictionary, not to sort the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only sort the *keys* (or items or values) of a dictionary, into a separate list (as I wrote years ago in the recipe that @Andrew's quoting). E.g., to sort keys according to your stated criteria:

```
promotion_items = {
    'one': {'remaining_pcs': 100, 'discount_ratio': 10},
    'two': {'remaining_pcs': 200, 'discount_ratio': 20},
}
def bypcs(k):
  return promotion_items[k]['remaining_pcs']
byrempcs = sorted(promotion_items, key=bypcs)
def bydra(k):
  return promotion_items[k]['discount_ratio']
bydiscra = sorted(promotion_items, key=bydra)
```

Comment: For the second `def bypcs` I suppose you meant `def bydra`?

Comment: @unutbu, right, and I see Mike Graham has already edited my A to fix this (tx both!).

Answer (score 2):

Please see [To sort a dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52306-to-sort-a-dictionary/):

> Dictionaries can't be sorted -- a
>   mapping has no ordering! -- so, when
>   you feel the need to sort one, you no
>   doubt want to sort its keys (in a
>   separate list).

Answer (score 0):

If `'remaining_pcs'` and `'discount_ratio'` are the only keys in the nested dictionaries then:

```
result = sorted(promotion_items.iteritems(), key=lambda pair: pair[1].items())
```

If there could be other keys then:

```
def item_value(pair):
    return pair[1]['remaining_pcs'], pair[1]['discount_ratio']
result = sorted(promotion_items.iteritems(), key=item_value)
```