# sort a dictionary according to their values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort by key of dictionary inside a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414763/sort-by-key-of-dictionary-inside-a-dictionary-in-python)

I have a dictionary:

```
d={'abc.py':{'map':'someMap','distance':11},
   'x.jpg':{'map':'aMap','distance':2},....}
```

Now what I need is: I need to sort `d` according to their distances?

I tried `sorted(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1,2)`, but it's not working.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictonary can't be sorted. So you have to convert your data to a list and sort this list.
Maybe you convert your dict to a list of tuples (key, value) and sort then.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot (really) influence the order in which your dict keys appear. If you want to iterate over the sorted keys, you could for instance use

```
sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: d[x]['distance'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]['distance'])
```